# E2E testing in a submodule of gradle project

Tags: gradle, continuous-integration, automated-tests

Let's say that my project have 2 modules, API, core and store, and I want to write some E2E tests for the core. My intention is that the final structure for test is:

```
root
  +- core
       +-src
          +-e2e
              +-java
```

Is it possible with gradle, or my only option is to put this tests as part of root project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, why wouldn't it be possible. There are many examples out there. Simplest solution is to define a new `sourceSet` and add a Test task to it.

```
sourceSets {
  e2e {
    java {
      compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
      runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
      srcDir file('src/e2e/java')
      resources.srcDir file('src/e2e/resources')
    }
  }
}

task e2eTest(type: Test) {
  testClassesDirs = sourceSets.e2e.output.classesDirs
  classpath = sourceSets.e2e.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Comment: It works. I was confused by the fact that the task appears in the main project in the Gradle plugin for IntelliJ.